# Can not pass traffic from privoxy to ziproxy

Tags: proxy, traffic-shaping, privoxy

To save up some bandwidth I decided to set up a privoxy and ziproxy bundle on my Debian Lenny VPS.

The idea was to have privoxy only accessible from localhost, and put ziproxy behind it to compress the output and accept connections, because it supports password authentication unlike privoxy, and I don't want to run a free for all proxy.

But they don't seem to work together for me. Each of them works separately just fine, but when I try to chain them adding

```
NextProxy = "127.0.0.1"
NextPort = 8118
```

to ziproxy config, ziproxy starts showing error 404.

The full configs look like this:

Ziproxy

```
Port = 100500
Address = "0.0.0.0"
NextProxy = "127.0.0.1"
NextPort = 8118
AccessLogFileName = "/var/log/ziproxy/access.log"
PasswdFile="/etc/ziproxy/http.passwd"
UseContentLength = false
Compressible = {
        "shockwave", "msword", "msexcel", "mspowerpoint", "rtf", "postscript",  
        "java", "javascript", "staroffice", "vnd.", "futuresplash", 
        "asp", "class", "font", "truetype-font", "php", "cgi", "executable",
        "shellscript", "perl", "python", "awk", "dvi", "css",
        "xhtml+xml", "rss+xml", "xml", "pdf", "tar"
}
ImageQuality = {20,15,15,15}
ModifySuffixes = false
```

Privoxy

```
user-manual /usr/share/doc/privoxy/user-manual
confdir /etc/privoxy
logdir /var/log/privoxy
actionsfile standard.action  # Internal purpose, recommended
actionsfile global.action    # Global default setting for all sites
actionsfile default.action   # Main actions file
actionsfile user.action      # User customizations
filterfile default.filter
logfile logfile
listen-address :8118
toggle  1
enable-remote-toggle  0
enable-remote-http-toggle  0
enable-edit-actions 0
enforce-blocks 0
buffer-limit 4096
forwarded-connect-retries  0
accept-intercepted-requests 1
allow-cgi-request-crunching 0
split-large-forms 0
```

I wonder what did I miss here?

Of course they both are down at the moment and of course when they start to collaborate listen-address for privoxy will be changed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't it enough to run ziproxy alone?

Comment: Well I'd like to have ads blocked as well. There is a tool to convert Adblock Plus rules for use with privoxy, I'd like to use it. I know I can blacklist things with ziproxy, but still.

Comment: Then again, both servers' developers stated they can be chained, and there are special options in config files. That means they _must_ be able to work together.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, I solved it.

It was all ziproxy's fault, the version which is in Lenny repo is buggy - doesn't chain and runs as root by default. So I just updated to Squeeze and it works just fine now.

None of other applications were harmed during update (postfix/dovecot/squirrelmail, prosody, apache and Dancer framework).

Not a good solution for 'serious' servers, though.